# Free an object in OnClose event of TForm

Tags: delphi, tform

I am new to Delphi and my question may be very basic.

I created a Form in a Delphi procedure. Until now, I was using `ShowModal()` and then freeing all the objects that I want to avoid leaking after closing the Form.

Now, I would like to show the Form modeless, but I don't know how I can free the objects inside the `OnClose` event.

Does anybody know a solution for it?

Comment: typically if you have objects that have the same life time as your form, you can use the `OnCreate`/`OnDestroy` events.

Comment: Thank you @whosrdaddy. But it is not working here because objects are created before form.

Comment: Then the form should not manage the lifetime of those objects. If you want to do this, you have a code smell...

Comment: I have an Image and want to display it in a form. The image is created before the form but basically when the form is closed the image should be also freed

Comment: Then let the form create the image?

Comment: That can be an option but still I don't now how can I overload an event in Delphi

Comment: From my experience, there is no need to overload an event in Delphi.  I'd go with @whosrdaddy 's answer: let the form create the image. Or create, use and free the image object within the form creation code.

Comment: Regardless of when and how the image is created, let the `TForm` object own the image.  The image will then be freed when the `TForm` object is freed. In the form's `OnClose` event, you can set the `Action` parameter to `caFree` to free the `TForm` object when it is closed.

Comment: WARNING: caFree is buggy under current (Sydney/10.4) implementation. The bug can be observed when skins are active! Closing a form with caFree will sometimes close the whole application. Skins are still supper buggy. One day (not soon) Embarcadero will fix the skins. Hopefully.

Comment: Another method would be to create the form using Application.CreateForm. Now the owner of the form will be the TApplication object. In this case the form will only be hidden (make sure this is really what you want) when the user presses the Close button. When the application shuts down it will take care of your form.

Comment: The above behavior is recommended when you want to form to leave all the time in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the `Action` parameter to `caFree`:

```
procedure TMyForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caFree;
end;
```

Per the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.OnClose):

> The value of the Action parameter determines if the form actually closes. These are the possible values of Action:
>
> caNone
>   The form is not allowed to close, so nothing happens.
>
> caHide
>   The form is not closed, but just hidden. Your application can still access a hidden form.
>
> **caFree
>
>   The form is closed and all allocated memory for the form is freed**.
>
> caMinimize
>   The form is minimized, rather than closed. This is the default action for MDI child forms.

Setting `Action` to `caFree` will cause the Form to call [`Release()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Release) on itself after the `OnClose` handler has exited:

> Destroys the form and frees its associated memory.
>
> Use Release to destroy the form and free its associated memory.
>
> Release does not destroy the form until all event handlers of the form and event handlers of components on the form have finished executing. Release also guarantees that all messages in the form's event queue are processed before the form is released. Any event handlers for the form or its children should use Release instead of Free (Delphi) or delete (C++). Failing to do so can cause a memory access error.
>
> Note: Release returns immediately to the caller. It does not wait for the form to be freed before returning.

`Release()` posts a delayed `CM_RELEASE` message to the Form window.  Once execution flow returns to the main message loop and the message is dispatched, the Form will free itself from memory.

If your `TForm` object owns other objects, they will be freed automatically when the `TForm` is freed.

Comment: WARNING: caFree is buggy under current (Sydney 10.4) implementation. The bug can be observed when skins are active! Closing a form with caFree will sometimes close the whole application.